# Extra Configurable Swatches showing on the Category Page

Tags: configurable-product, magmi, swatches, color-swatches

On our product listings page, two of our products have color swatches showing up beneath them which should not be there,  one of them does not even have any configurable color options set but is showing them anyway.

The other has 4 color options that should be there but 8 that shouldn't.  The 4 that should be there are swapping the main product image correctly while the 8 that shouldn't are sometimes swapping the product image and sometimes for a different product image entirely.

I've checked that the color attribute is correctly set for all the associated products and they are, I've also cleared the cache and re-indexed.

I've looked in the **template/configurableswatches/catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml** file and see that `$_attrValues = $_product->getListSwatchAttrValues()` is responsible for getting the list of swatches on the product listings page but that's as far as I could debug it.

Any idea where Magento is getting the list of swatches from, is it from a DB table.  Any other advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it seemed that this issue was caused by the Magmi Mass importer tool which I used to add the products.

With it you import configurable products by specifying which attribute will be used to make the product configurable & listing the associated products before hand, it seems magmi was also adding the configurable attributes of the simple products which preceded the associated products even though they did not have a value in the `configurable_attributes` column.

I solved the issue by deleting the two configurable products and recreating them.